# How to migrate Ubercart Shop (drupal 6) to another CMS / Shop system as Commerce, Magento, etc?

Tags: 6, commerce, ubercart, migrations

How to migrate Ubercart Shop (drupal 6) to another CMS / Shop system as Commerce, Magento, etc...

Is there any easy way to migrate a Drupal 6 Ubercart store to another CMS or shop system?

What would you use instead of Drupal Ubercart?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. **How to migrate Ubercart Shop (drupal 6) to another CMS / Shop system as Commerce, Magento, etc...**

A typical approach to migrate such site to D7 is to use the [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module.

> 2. **Is there any easy way to migrate a Drupal 6 Ubercart store to another CMS or shop system?**

Using the [Commerce Migrate Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_migrate_ubercart) module will pretty sure simplify things. Some details from its project page:

> *Commerce Migrate Ubercart is a migration using [Commerce Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_migrate) and the [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) suite that can migrate 6.x and 7.x Ubercart stores from either the existing Drupal database or an external database on the same machine.*

Since this includes D6 and Ubercart, you should definitely have a look at this module if you go for [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce)

> 3. **What would you use instead of Drupal Ubercart?**

Going for the [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module is definitely an option you should consider, and the modules mentioned above should help (a lot?) to get you there.